# operation on closed csv file ValueError, Python Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, valueerror

I am currently writing a script to read two columns of float numbers in a CSV file and find the average of each column. I do not understand why my code is giving me a ValueError I/O operation on closed file.

My code has two open statements since to my understanding you must close the file and reopen it before adding and finding the average to a second column.

My code is below, I appreciate any feedback I can get on this, It is not making sense to me. Thank you.

Language: Python 3.6

```
def main():
    import csv

    file = input("What is the name of the file, dont forget the .csv: ")
    INFILE = open(file,"r")
    totalCol1 = 0
    countCol1 = 0
    totalCol2 = 0
    countCol2 = 0
    read = csv.reader(INFILE,lineterminator=",")

    # Loop through column 1
    for row in read:
        totalCol1 += float(row[0])
        countCol1 += 1
    averageCol1 = totalCol1 / countCol1
    INFILE.close()

    INFILE = open(file,"r")
    for row in read:
        totalCol2 += float(row[1])
        countCol2 += 1
    averageCol2 = totalCol2 / countCol2

    print('Average for Column One:%5.2f' % averageCol1)
    print('Average for Column Two:%5.2f' % averageCol2)
    INFILE.close()

main()
```

Comment: you don't need to close the file and reopen it.  you can access all columns in one loop

Comment: Thank you @jdigital I have no idea where I got the idea to need two loops. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what's happening is that you pass an instance of INFILE to csv.reader that then gets closed. So when you open the file again you need to pass that new instance to csv.reader.

That being said though, you can do all of this in the first loop without having to close and reopen the file:

```
for row in read:
    totalCol1 += float(row[0])
    countCol1 += 1

    totalCol2 += float(row[1])
    countCol2 += 1

averageCol1 = totalCol1 / countCol1
averageCol2 = totalCol2 / countCol2
```

or you could just use pandas [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to read the csv and then calculate the average using pandas [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and avoid looping (a worthwhile endeavor in Python).

Comment: Perfect thank you, Im not sure where I got the idea that i needed two loops....that was definitely my bad. Thanks for the help